# How can I make a neck and body for my head mesh?

Tags: mesh

[image: My Mesh***Looks like this***]

I tried to create a neck and I succeeded. But when I try to turn the neck into shoulders it just doesn't work. (I mostly sculpted) (most of the mesh is sculpted)
can anyone help?

Comment: Extrude and scale is your friend.

Comment: Based on your screen grab you are in Sculpt Mode. What you are asking to do should be done in Edit Mode. I would suggest that you create a "Make Human" model and study its mesh.

Comment: Actually, this question is primarily opinion based. Everyone has there own way to model the rest of the body. I have my own extrude system, and I am sure everyone else who does character modeling has there own way as well. If you are looking for ideas, you should either ask for ideas in chat, or go to the Blender Artist Forum

Comment: It is hard to teach you how to model from beginner to pro in a single answer. Sculpting is fun but you'll soon end up with a mesh with a very large number of polygons and terrible topology. There are countless "tutorials" that show you how to create anthropomorphic figures (I presume your character is one) https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=blender+model+human+body+tutorial&oq=blender+model+human&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.0j0i22i30k1l3.3148.11329.0.13468.39.29.10.0.0.0.107.2414.27j2.29.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.39.2434...35i39k1j0i131k1j0i67k1j0i10k1j0i13k1j0i22i10i30k1.XK77akrLieo

Comment: That head could be a start for some really fun project like cartoon sculptures created in antiquity. However I fail to see a neck there.

Comment: I'd install this into Blender-  http://www.manuelbastioni.com/manuellab.php  -then scale & pose one to fit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to sculpting you could click the Dynamesh button (in this gif I also checked constant detail and upped the resolution).

I used the snakehook brush here, but the normal clay brush works too (the grab brush does not work though, it does not add new typology).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to sculpt it. Go into edit mode, select the edge on one of the sides of the neck (to make the shoulder) and press E to extrude it out. (I'd recommend extruding it while it orthographic view and pressing 1 on the number pad so it doesn't move backwards or forwards. As for the body, that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to add to the first 2 answers, I would just

- start over with a cube in edit mode,
- and I would press the 'w' key while it is orange
- and add a sub divide line
- and I would press the 'a' key to get it out of its orange stage.
- Then I would delete all of the vertices on the left side of the cube,
- and then I would go over to the right under the properties tabs
- and I would click on the wrench looking icon,
- and then I would click on add modifiers,
- and then I would add mirror
- and then I would click on the add modifiers popup menu again
- and I would add subdivision surface,
- and then I would put a check on the clippings settings,
- and then I would go down and make sure I would have the same number of subdivisions view as the render, 2 should be enough,
- and then I would go down to the bottom tool bar where your edit mode is and click on the magnet icon to snap to the nearest grid line,
- and then I would go to the object view,
- and go to the left tool bar and click on smooth
- and then I go back into edit mode to press the '#5' on the numpad
- and also click on the '#1' on the numpad,
- and then the 'c' key
- and then I would highlight the right side's 4 panels,
- and then I would move it to the left 4 times,
- and then I would highlight the bottom 4 panels
- and then I would extrude it down 2 times 1 whole grids down,
- and then I would go under the middle subdivision line and click there and press the "ctrl + R" keys
- and right click twice to snap the vertices in the middle,
- and then I would highlight that middle section, all four sides,
- and then I would make sure to press on the 'e'  and 's' and the 'x' keys in that order,
- and then I would first move it to the left 2 times, click out of it
- and then press the same three keys again, but this time I would go to the left 6 times,
- and then I click on the numpad '#3' key,
- and then I would press the 'e' and the 's' and the 'y' keys and go to the left 3 times,
- and then click out of that,
- and then I would click on the green error and go to the right 3 times,
- and voilà, you have your first head and neck and body structure

enjoy!! these are the steps to take

1. start with a cube.
2. add a subdivision line, and delete entire left side.
3. go to the properties tab. Add a mirror from the modifiers and then check the box for clippings and add the subdivision surface. And, make sure you add the same number of views as the render.
4. click on the magnet icon at the bottom tool bar
5. click off or turn off the snowflake looking icon at the bottom toolbar.
6. highlight the right most 4 panels, and then snap them to the left 4 times or 4 places.
7. highlight the 4 bottom panels or faces and press the 'e' key to extrude it down 2 x 1 whole grids.
8. snap a vertices under the middle section.
9. highlight the middle section, press the 'e' and 's' and 'x' keys and move to the left 2 times, then click out it and press the same keys again and go to the left 6 times..
10. Press the #3 on the numpad, then press the 'e' and 's' and 'y' keys and go to the left 3 times, and then click out of that and drag the green arrow 2 times to the right...

but after step 4 go to the object view and click on the smooth feature on the left hand toolbar...

Comment: Hi, please, in future,use bullet points/numbered tools, in the editor, to make it easier for others to follow your step by step instructions... maybe some description image would also help...